# Vim: How to have YouCompleteMe autocomplete shell script variable names and functions from "source"d files?

Tags: autocompletion, macvim, plugin-you-complete-me, shell

I use macvim with YouCompleteMe (YCM), which I recently updated and recompiled. I followed the YCM instructions for OSX.  I'm also using iterm2, tmux and zsh, all of which are installed with brew and updated.

YCM autocompletion of variable names and shell functions that are defined *in the shell script itself* work as intended.

However, with my current setup, YCM will not autocomplete variable names and shell functions from files sourced with `source` in this shell script.

I have verified that files were sourced correctly, because the script functions properly.

All files sourced are in the same directory as the sourcing script, and are sourced with relative pathnames with slashes.  One file, `init.sh`, has no `#!` and contains only variables.  The second, `functions.sh` has a `#!` (which isn't really necessary for my use case) and function definitions. No variables are used in specifying the sourced files. So:

```
source "./init.sh"
source "./functions.sh"
```

I've made sure to `source ~/.vimrc` and restart the YCM server after any changes, and verify that YCM logs in my vim session contain no errors, after any change to my files.

How can I get YCM to autocomplete these items?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Thanks @filbranden!  Update: I got some very helpful suggestions from the YCM folks: using the YCM bash language server https://github.com/ycm-core/lsp-examples (which didn't work), and using ctags and this: https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#the-gycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files-option .  I'm currently working on the second idea, but I don't fully understand tags yet.

Comment: I'm not a user of YCM myself so I can't give you many pointers about that... Regarding tags, you install a `ctags` program and use `ctags -R .` at the top level of your project, it will find all source files in it and create a pretty large file named `tags` that serves as index to where things are defined. Note that Vim has native support for tag files, for example you can use `<C-]>` (Ctrl + ] -- the close bracket) to jump to definition of the term under the cursor.

Comment: One downside of using tags is that you need to keep the tags file up to date, but there are plug-ins that can help with that. I have used vim-gutentags in the past for this purpose and I've been happy with the way it works. There are others too, make your research...

Comment: If you find more topics (such as tags, or LSPs) that you need help with, feel free to ask separate questions about those here. It's a great community here, many prolific plug-in writers and core Vim/NeoVim contributors hang around here, so you're likely to get great answers. I hope you have fun! :-)

Comment: Great, thanks @filbranden, that's really helpful info about how tags work.  I will edit the question to be YCM-centric, since that's kind of how I originally phrased it (although I didn't even know about the existence of tags when I wrote it).  That being said, it seems that tags will likely need to be involved, whether used with YCM, or on their own with a `ctags` program and vim plugin like you mentioned.  I look forward to asking more questions, I'm pretty set on making vim into my IDE. thanks again!

Comment: The specific `source` lines in your shell script might be relevant here... Are you sourcing from script files in the same directory, a relative directory or an absolute directory? Are you sourcing by a fixed pathname or using variables to specify the path or name of file to source?

Comment: Super good question..so I read `man bash` for this, and decided to do relative pathnames with slashes, for instance `source "./functions.sh"` All sources so far in in the same directory, root of project.

Comment: I wanted to make sure `bash` didn't search my `PATH` so I opted for slashes. No variable names in the sourced files, just to avoid having to write a lot of "" and {} Any thoughts? The sourced files with just variables in them have no #! and are not executable (I don't think this matters), and the shell functions files do have #!, and are executable. Although now that I think of it, if you execute a script with shell functions in it, they won't be exported into the current shell, you have to source them, afaik, so this isn't necessary.

Comment: Strangely, this all working in one project directory, but not another, with identical structure as mentioned above.  I was super careful with sourcing `.vimrc` and restarting vim, and checking the YCMD server status, which was working.

Comment: This is all good! Tags should help you here and LSP should as well... Please make sure you [edit] your question and include the information about sourcing `./functions.sh` and similar, files in same directory, including `#!`, etc. The question should be as complete as possible (not everyone will look through all the comments ...)